# Centos 7.7 remove dupplicate php 7.2 version

Tags: centos, php7

I'm working with centos 7.7 and the client has provided me with a vm where they unawarely installed the same version of PHP, which is 7.2, two times in two different ways, one of which is by remi's repository, the other I'm not sure about probably yum install php72-php.

I've configured remi's php with fpm and nginx, I'd like to remove the other one as the app I'm using recalls some php script and somehow use the other php which is missing modules and also adds entropy. Is it possible? If not Is it possible to make remi's php 7.2 the default one?

Any help is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read the repository FAQ about [differences between php-* and php72-php-* packages](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

If you need a single version, you only need "php-*" packages, so you can remove the "php72-php-*" packages

```
yum remove php72-\*
```

Proper installation is explained by the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

Comment: So ideally I've to remove both and then go with a clean install?

Comment: This can be a cleaner solution, btw, not mandatory, cleanup the SCL and check the extension list of the single installed version, remove unneeded ones, and install missing.

Comment: one more last question, the vm is actually aws ec2 instance. We need php-fpm along with nginx, i noticed that if i put the sockets in /run/php at reboot, sockets and the dir is missing is lost but if i put it undet /etc/opt/remi/... it doesn't occur. After the solution you proposed how could i do to save the sockets?

Comment: Keep socket in default location ;)

Comment: noob question: which is?

Comment: The one configured in the default pool (wwww.conf), so /var/run/php-fpm for base package. This directory is created during service startup, which is probably not suitable for container... so you have to create it by hand in your Dockerfile

Comment: thanks I'll ask client's sys admin to adjust the configs